# using duplicated javascript variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, uislider

So on my page I have data which is output as:

```
   var firststep = 1;
   var secondstep = 2;
   var thirdstep = 3;
   var fourstep = 4;

   var firststep = 1;
   var secondstep = 2;
   var thirdstep = 3;
   var fourstep = 4;
```

The values are actually output by the server, however I need to reuse the values independantly. I can pass an additional value such as:

```
   var category = flight;
```

but the rest of the values are as above.

I'm trying to use multiple sliders for example, but the two sliders both use the last JS vars, I pass them via:

```
  $scope.first[1]=firststep;
  $scope.first[2]=secondstep;
  $scope.first[3]=thirdstep;
  $scope.first[4]=fourstep;
```

however can't figure out how I can handle multiple situations that use the same vars.

Comment: Redundant `var` declarations are collapsed as if there were only one. Thus, if your code writes two `var firststep` declarations, there's really only one variable "firststep".

Comment: What would be the easiest way to do this? could I do this with a data-attribute? As I just have access to these vars.

Comment: As @Pointy pointed out, multiple var declarations of the same variable name are collapsed into one and the last assigned value overwrites all others. Perhaps we might be able to come  up with a solution if you can provide more information as far as how the variables are generated by the server and injected into the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you use multiple sliders with same variable names, then you should wrap those variables into an object/model.

e.g in controller's scope

```
$scope.default_values = {
    firststep: 1,
    secondstep: 2,
    thirdstep: 3,
    fourthstep: 4,
};
$scope.slider_1_values = angular.copy($scope.default_values);
$scope.slider_2_values = angular.copy($scope.default_values);
```

and then in your view/controller you use the appropriate slider_1_values or slider_2_values object. you can use ng-model="slider_1_values" to make an input use specific object as its model.

---

I think the best option in your case is to turn the slider into a "directive"
so you can re-use a slider with different variables, by assigning it a different model.

```
<custom-slider ng-model="slider_1_values"></custom-slider>
<custom-slider ng-model="slider_2_values"></custom-slider>

app.directive('customSlider', function() {
    return {
        "restrict": "E",
        "templateUrl": "yourslider_theme.html",
        "controller": function($scope) {
            //depending on the ng-model="" your 
            $scope.values now contain a different set of same variables
        },
        "link": function($scope, $element, $attr) {
            $scope.values = $scope[$attr['ngModel']];
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: In my code I basically reuse the scope variables by declaring the variable function:

        $scope.values=function(value){
         return $scope.first[value];
         }

and then later call it 

     $scope.values($scope.slide['slider_1'])

Would it not be easier to change the scope.values function to separate based on the name?

Comment: Probably not.

The thing you are trying to do, is what directives are meant for in angular imo.